# "A communications failure has occurred between the Backup Exec job engine and the remote agent" for a local restore

Tags: backup, backupexec

I am having a problem with my restore using Backup Exec 16. On the face of it, I would think that an error like "A communications failure has occurred between the Backup Exec job engine and the Agent for Windows" is due to a blocked firewall port, but after plugging through logs I came across this:

[image]

I am not sure what to make of this. Restoring directly to the remote server shows a similar error in the same category:

Error category    : Resource Errors
Error             : e00084f9

So I think I need some wisdom imparted! Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you test the logon account credentials?

It is either an issue with those or with the server-name you are using. The logs point out an issue with either the DNS name or the logon account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Florian, I can logon with that user account. The servername is the local host in this case, so I am not seeing why that would be a problem.

Comment: You have a DNS/Name resolving issue as from what I can see in you log snipped. You should check details there. It also could be that there is a restriction on the RemoteAgent-Configuration - there is a Backup Exec Agent Utility in the Start menu - Alternative try creating a new user account - but I doubt that's the core issue.

Comment: Sorry about the late response. I opened a ticket with Veritas, and they're working with me on it. I will let you know what becomes of it. From the command line, I can resolve the name of the client, so I do not know where it is getting stuck.

Comment: Florian, I apologize for the slow response. Thanks for your comment - it did get me on the right track, because in Backup Exec Settings -> Network and Security, the Network interface was set to "Use any available network interface", and should have been set to the NIC that's available to the clients. I'm marking your comment as the answer.